# Text manipulation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to write a word counter for LyX files.

Life is almost very simple as most lines that need to be ignored begin with a `\` (I'm prepared to make the assumption that no textual lines begin with backslashes) - however there are some lines that look like real text that aren't, but they are enclosed by `\begin_inset` and `\end_inset`:

```
I'm genuine text.

\begin_inset something
I'm not real text
Perhaps there will be more than one line! Or none at all! Who knows.
\end_inset

/begin_layout
I also need to be counted, and thus not removed
/end_layout
```

Is there a quick way in ruby to strip the (smallest amount of) text *between* two markers? I'm imagining Regular Expressions are the way forward, but I can't figure out what they'd have to be.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a quick way in ruby to strip the (smallest amount of) text between two markers?

```
str = "lala BEGIN_MARKER \nlu\nlu\n END_MARKER foo BEGIN_MARKER bar END_MARKER baz"
str.gsub(/BEGIN_MARKER.*?END_MARKER/m, "")
#=> "lala  foo  baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

gsub could be expensive for longer files (if you're reading in the whole file as string)

so if you have to chunk it anyway, you might want to use a **stateful parser**

```
in_block = false
File.open(fname).each_line do |line| 
 if in_block
    in_block = false if line =~ /END_MARKER/
    next
  else
    in_block = true if line =~ /BEGIN_MARKER/
    next
  end
  count_words(line)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [str.scan()](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.src/M000812.html). Assuming your text is in the variable s, something like this should work:

```
s_strip_inset = s.sub!(/\\begin_inset.*?\\end_inset/, "")
word_count = s_strip_inset.scan(/(\w|-)+/).size
```